# How do I move armor stands in Minecraft 1.8/1.8.1 with command blocks to different locations of the world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way that I can move these four armor stands with command blocks?

Comment: what did you try allready?

Comment: Please limit your questions to a single one per question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tp` command to move the armor stands. e.g.:

`/tp @e[type=ArmorStand] <co-ordinates of where you want to move the armor stand>`

But be careful  - this will move all armor stand in the world to that location. If you want to specify an armor stand you can use the `r=` tag. e.g.: `/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,r=1] <co-ordinates>` this will move all armor stands in a radius of 1 of where the command was executed. So if you were to type the command in chat you must be in a radius of 1 block of the Armor Stand to move it.

To control difficulty you can simply type the command: `/difficulty <difficulty level>`
Difficulty levels are:

- 0 = Peaceful
- 1 = Easy
- 2 = Normal
- 3 = Hard

So if you wanted to change the difficulty to peaceful, you can use this command: `/difficulty 0`

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Er.. there is no /to command.. and why is /difficulty mentioned?

Comment: @PangeaCake difficulty is mentioned because clapynick answered before MrLemon edited that part out. Edit summary: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/199114/revisions